# Unable to automatically step into server. unable to determine a stopping location

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a VB.NET VS2010 solution with a WinForms project that calls a web site project in the same solution.

I can step into this web method:
`<WebMethod()> Public Function GetStartUpData() As DataSet`

and other web methods, but not the following method. I wonder if it has to do with the fact that that is the only web method that uses a parameter of Nullable type.

The method works, I just can't step into it .If I try, I get the error:

> Unable to automatically step into server. unable to determine a stopping location

Is this a bug? Is there a work-around?

```
<WebMethod()> 
Public Function RetrieveOrdersByFilter( _
   ByVal customerId As Nullable(Of Integer), _
   ByVal fromDate As Nullable(Of Date), _
   ByVal toDate As Nullable(Of Date), _
   ByVal fromStatusCodeId As Nullable(Of Integer), _
   ByVal toStatusCodeId As Nullable(Of Integer))  As DataSet
```

Answer (score 5):

For those who enter here, my solution was by setting the output to "Debug".. silly I know...

Did found it through Leniel's links :)

Answer (score 4):

There is an option in Tools -> Options -> Debugging _> General called '`Enable Just My Code`', unchecking this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles here, i also had this problem, but my solution was different than what is posted so far.

My issue was that my application pool for my web service was running .net 4 when my application (an older one) was expecting .net 2.

While still functional, i was unable to debug my web service until i created an application pool for it in IIS that used .net 2.

Answer (score 0):

I my case it stumbled because not all dependency assemblies of the web service exist in the folder where the web service is running, with the detailed exception could figure out the missing ones

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and all I needed to do was copy the [your_dll_file_name].pdb file and it was able to attach to the code.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same  issue in VS 2013.

I just replaced the target framework from 4.0 to 4.5 in web.config of the called project as shown below:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I set my solution to start multiple projects and start both the Service and the desktop app.  Then set a breakpoint on the service function in question.  You still get the error if you try to F11 into the WS, but it will jump to your code that has a breakpoint.